# Drag and Drop into TextBox within an MVVM DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a View defined using a DataTemplate. I would like to be able to drag a file into a TextBox on my View to populate it with a full filename. However, since my View is a DataTemplate it has no code-behind and I can’t see how I can hook up DragEnter and Drag events.

Is there a tidy way to do this in MVVM?

Comment: Can you post your code, it is easy then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DataTemplate resides in a resource dictionary, it is possible to create an associated code-behind file.

Say your resource dictionary is called "Foo.xaml". Create a class file of the same name (i.e. "Foo.cs") in the same project folder, make it partial, and have it inherit from ResourceDictionary. Also, call `InitializeComponent()` in the constructor:-

```
public partial class Foo : ResourceDictionary
{
    public Foo()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }

    // etc..
}
```

Now in your xaml, add an `x:Class=` attribute to the ResourceDictionary element, e.g.:-

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="Namespace.ClassName"
                    xmlns="...etc...
```

You should now find that you can add events to your controls, just like you would in a UserControl.

Comment: Awesome. That worked perfectly. Thank you. I had no idea you could add a code behind class to a ResourceDictionary.